# In Logstash HTTP input, how can I send the error to the client instead of nothing?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

these are my logstash settings

```
input {
    http {
        port => 5000
        codec => "json"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "changeme"
    }
}
```

if I do `curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:5000' -d '{"message": "hello"}'` and get an error I'm not getting any feedback in CURL. I can see the error in my logstash / elastic stack console, but I'd like to get it also in curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input and output stages in Logstash are completely disconnected and run asynchronously.

Your `http` input will always respond 200 OK because your message has been accepted for processing. The fact that the `elasticsearch` output fails to properly index your message cannot be propagated back to the input, and hence to your curl call.

The sequence goes like this:

1. you invoke curl on port 5000
2. the `http` input receives your message and responds 200 OK
   -> At this point, your curl command returns
3. the `http` input then sends your message through the filter and output pipeline
4. the `elasticsearch` output receives the message to be handled
5. the `elasticsearch` output sends the message to Elasticsearch
6. Elasticseach complains about the message and sends 400 Error
7. the `elasticsearch` output dumps that error in the Logstash log

You can read more about the [Logstash execution model](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/execution-model.html).